# Firebase Lists vs Objects

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

quick question about Firebase lists.

I'm trying to access multiple lists to iterate through that are in a single object. The object looks like this:

```
user : {
    playlists: {}, // List 1
    joined: {},    // List 2
    favorites: {}  // List 3
}
```

Now I know I can access all three lists by doing three separate requests like:

```
firebase.list('user/playlists');
firebase.list('user/joined');
firebase.list('user/favorites');
```

But I'm trying to clean up my code and do it all in one by using:

```
firebase.list('user');
```

Then accessing all the lists it returns inside of the user. The only problem is, the lists aren't returned with keys, it just says "object" instead. When I use `firebase.object('user')` the keys are available.

This is what it looks like when I request 'user' as a list:

[image]

As you can see the key is inside the object and not outside of it ($key). How do I go about accessing these objects like I would if the key was actually the key (eg. user.playlists).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested I figured it out. I used the `.map()` to convert parts of the object into arrays.

```
getPlaylist(_playlistId: string, _query: Object = {}) {

  return this._database.object(`playlists/${_playlistId}`, _query).map(

      result => {

        return {
          info: result.info,
          leader: result.leader,
          favorites: (result.favorites) ? Object.values(result.favorites) : [],
          followers: (result.followers) ? Object.values(result.followers) : [],
          songs: (result.songs) ? Object.values(result.songs) : []
        };

      }

    );
  }
```

For example, favorites is an object that I want to be returned as a list:

```
 Check if exists      If exists, map obj to array     else assign to empty array
(result.favorites) ? Object.values(result.favorites) : []
```